# ValueError: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False. You should leave random_state to its default (None), or set shuffle=True

Tags: python, pycaret

When i try to train some thing in pycreat i recive this error message

`ValueError: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False. You should leave random_state to its default (None), or set shuffle=True.`

```
from pycaret.regression import *
clf1 = setup(data = df, target = 'Survived',train_size = 0.7, session_id = 2)

best=compare_models()
```

Comment: What was the meaning of "SOS idk" in your question and the `sos` tag?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

for pycaret 2.2.3

```
exp_clf101 = setup(data = df, target = 'Survived',  fold_shuffle=True, session_id=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had this issue. The problem was that scikit-learn version has had a major updated from version 0.X.X to 1.X.X, and Pycaret works with version [0.23.2](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/blob/master/requirements.txt).
**Solution: re-install the older version in your env.**

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following:

```
from pycaret.classification import *
clf1 = setup(data = df, target = 'Survived', train_size = 0.7, data_split_shuffle=True, session_id = 2)


best=compare_models()
```