# Pycaret anomaly detection setup: ValueError: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False

Tags: python, anomaly-detection, pycaret

I have recently transitioned from R to python, and I am not sure how to problem solve the following.

When I run the setup for pycaret anomaly detection, following the instructions that can be found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-anomaly-detection-with-pycaret-706a6e2b2427), on my own data I get the following error.

```
# Inital setup
s = setup(data, session_id = 1230)
ValueError: Setting a random_state has no effect since shuffle is False. You should leave random_state to its default (None), or set shuffle=True.
```

The only difference from the example is that I have some additional xregs (base_price(float64), sale_price(float64), promotion_flag(int64; 0 or 1)). As I understand it, this shouldn't affect the results, after all there are a number of time features. Everything else is the same. So I don't understand why this error is occurring.

I tried the answers on this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67728802/valueerror-setting-a-random-state-has-no-effect-since-shuffle-is-false-you-sho), along with adding `shuffle=True`, but these all resulted in a `unexpected keyword argument`.

I appreciate this may be a bit basic, but the error doesn't make sense to me, based on what I have done. Thanks for your time.

Python 3.7.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this question is that the environment I was using in anaconda had library versions such as `numpy` that were too new for `pycaret` to work with, for example, pycaret need numpy (1.19.5 and will not work with newer).

My solution was to create a new environment in anaconda, which used `pip install pycaret[full]`, and added nothing else to the environment. It worked after this.